# Python Selenium unable to login by clicking on Button inside a form

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

website: https://www.etoro.com/login

I am trying to click on Sign in button by xpath :

Code trial:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/ui-layout/div/div/div[1]/login/login-sts/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div[4]/button").click()
```

But failed to do so. Tried by css and by class also but unable to login.

When I am trying to login manually then it login successfully but while through selenium python it failed to do so.

Page only showing an error: "An error occurred ,please try again" Is there any suggestions, what to do or what I am not getting here?

```html
<button automation-id="login-sts-btn-sign-in" ng-click="loginCtrl.login(loginForm)" class="e-btn-big wide dark pointer">Sign in</button>
```

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/ui-layout/div/div/div[1]/login/login-sts/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div[4]/button").click()
```

Expected result would be a successfull login and render to the dashboard of my account.

Comment: Try to open the login url using selenium chromedriver and then fill in your user and pass manually and then press on log-in button manually @Etoro Test. I highly doubt you can get logged in.

Comment: Tried it but unfortunately it doesn't works.. sometimes it worked (2 times) but other time doesnt works...

Comment: That is the reason your script is unable to do that.

Comment: Pardon, cann't get the reason..please tell me where am I fauling?

Comment: You are failing nowhere. What I'm saying is that when you put your credentials opening a browser manually then it works but  when you do the same after opening a broswer using selenium then it fails. To be clearer: just consider this three lines of code `from selenium import webdriver;driver= webdriver.Chrome() ;driver.get("https://www.etoro.com/login")`. When you execute it, you can see a browser. Now, put your credentials manually to log in. It will fail.

Comment: Yes, But cannot find the solution for the same...why is it happening? What may be the reason behind that..? Is there ant difference between normal browser and chromedriver? why is it not accepting the credentials? (But it accepts 2 times )That does not make any sense to me... Please let me know too... and how can I get into the dashboard after successful login either by opening url via webdriver and inputs manually  ?

Comment: I have the same issue. Any update?

Answer (score 1):

To send a character sequence to a *Username* and *Password* field's, and also invoke a `click()` on an element with text as  **Sign in** as value ,you need to induce a *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and after that you will be able to use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  driver= webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.etoro.com/login")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.w-login-main-form-input.ng-valid-email.ng-invalid-required.ng-valid-pattern"))).send_keys("Etoro")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.w-login-main-form-input[type='password']").send_keys("Test")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.e-btn-big.wide.dark.pointer[automation-id='login-sts-btn-sign-in']").click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: etoro]

Comment: That is the main error I have been encountering everytime I am trying to click..... I have tried your solution too but still not getting the output /Login ... Is there something in their script which can differentiate Bot and manual inputs.. because I have found while inspect i.e ng-keyup=. $event.keyCode == 13 ? loginCtrl.login(loginForm) : null ...I suggest you to please look at that inspect element

Comment: But then you need to help the contributors with a working set of credentials.

Comment: I tried with a working set of credentials and I can't go further. Is it possible that EToro knows that I am using Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install chromedriver and chrome. You can change these settings for other browsers if you want. This work fine for me.

My OS: Ubuntu 16.04

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")

browser.get('<login_url>')

username = browser.find_element_by_name("<username_name_tag>")
password = browser.find_element_by_name("<password_name_tag>")

username.send_keys("<username>")
password.send_keys("<password>")

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@automation-id='login-sts-btn-sign-in' and @value='Sign in']").click()
```

Comment: I have tried it earlier but it does not works... Suggesting to please visit website once... would appreciate your efforts..

Comment: Site not opening :( @EtoroTest

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@automation-id='login-sts-btn-sign-in' and @value='Sign in']").click() **Try this** I have edited

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@automation-id='login-sts-btn-sign-in']").click() brings same error on page while xpath with value='Sign in' provided by you will raise error by webdriver itself... problem still the same

Comment: My last suggestion: **browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".e-btn-big[value='Sign in']").click()**